# Angular 11 - TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, fetch, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am using a dependency which itself depends on [isomorphic-unfetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch).
In an Angular 11 project, I can execute isomorphic-unfetch itself without any errors.
When using the dependency (installed via npm), which internally uses isomorphic-unfetch to fetch, I receive the following message:

```
index.js:209 TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation
at zone-evergreen.js:1465
at Object.proto.<computed> [as default] (zone-evergreen.js:975)
at index.js:189
at step (index.js:70)
at Object.next (index.js:51)
at index.js:44
at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:1387)
at __awaiter (index.js:40)
at index.js:380
```

The dependency is working fine when integrated in React or plain JS/TS.
I found some related questions on here that did not target Angular in specific.

Answer (score 0):

As Angular provides their own library for making http requests `HttpClientModule` and `HttpClient` there is usually no need for third party libraries like `unfetch` etc. This is the reason nobody targets Angular in the docs or other places.

But it should still be possible to use the library. Some hints that I can think of went wrong in your case:

- `Window` is written with a capital `W` instead of a `w`.
- Maybe you need to initialize some peer dependencies like `import 'unfetch'` to run their default script (which will then add the fetch function to the window object)